# Approach for taking action on reception of two different JMS messages

Tags: jms, spring-jms

Say I have one JMS message `FooCompleted`

```
{"businessId": 1,"timestamp": "20140101 01:01:01.000"}
```

and another JMS message `BazCompleted`

```
{"businessId": 1,"timestamp": "20140101 01:02:02.000"}
```

The use case is that I want some action triggered when both messages have been received for the business id in question - essentially a join point of reception of the two messages. The two messages are published on two different queues and order between reception of `FooCompleted` and `BazCompleted` may change. In reality, I may need to have join of reception of several different messages for the businessId in question.

The naive approach was that to store the reception of the message in a db and check if message(s) its dependent join arm(s) have been received and only then kick off the action desired. Given that the problem seems generic enough, we were wondering if there is a better way to solve this.

Another thought was to move messages from these two queues into a third queue on reception. The listener on this third queue will be using a special avataar of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which overrides the `doReceiveAndExecute` to call `receiveMessage` for all outstanding messages in the queue and adding messages back to the queue whose all dependent messages have not yet arrived - the remaining ones will be acknowledged and hence removed. Given that the quantum of messages will be low, probing the queue over and adding messages again should not be a problem. The advantage would be avoiding the DB dependency and the associated scaffolding code. Wanted to see if there is something glaringly bad with this

Gurus, please critique and point out better ways to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) with a JMS message-driven adapter and an aggregator with custom correlation and release strategies, and a peristent (JDBC) message store will provide your first solution without writing much (or any) code.

Comment: thanks - do you see any problems in going with #2? If not, are you aware of an implementation that provides what we need here?